# How using LINE chat bot "reply_message function" to reply multi-messages to user

Tags: python, chatbot

I'm trying to use **reply_message** function to send back multi-messages to user, but I got some trouble in there.

In the official SDK document we know how to using the reply_message function example is:

```
line_bot_api.reply_message(event.reply_token, TextSendMessage(text = "123"))
```

And then the Line bot will show the message "123" if user send something messages.

But in the official github it said that "reply_message" function can send 
5 messages at same time.

official github Screenshot

[image]

[official github link](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/blob/master/linebot/api.py)

Also, the document said that the request body should send back two parameters:
replyToken and messages (please see the screenshot)
[offical reply_message SDK document link](https://developers.line.me/en/reference/messaging-api/#send-reply-message)

[image: the SDK document of reply message function screenshot]

It said put **the array of message object** into message parameter.
And the array of message object is look like:
[the SDK document of message object example link](https://developers.line.me/en/reference/messaging-api/#message-objects)

[image: the SDK document of message object screenshot]

Another way I found that someone using PHP to implement by using this function.

[PHP implement method example](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-php/issues/28)

But I still can't find the solution how to send multi messages in the reply_message function by using Python..

I tried to code in Python is:

```
line_bot_api.reply_message({'reply_token' : event.reply_token, 'messages' : [{'type' : 'text', 'text' : '123'}]})
```

The error message is:

**TypeError: reply_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'messages'**

error message log

[image]

I tried another way to put parameters, but still can't work

```
line_bot_api.reply_message(reply_token = event.reply_token, messages = [{'type' : 'text', 'text' : '123'}])
```

the error message is:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'as_json_dict'
```

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: you are missing a parameter called 'messages'. thats why it wont run.

Comment: @javajav Thank you for your replying. But I can't find how to send multi messages into the "messages" parameter. Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution.

Here is the example:

```
line_bot_api.reply_message(event.reply_token, [TextSendMessage(text= reply_text), TextSendMessage(text= reply_text1)])
```

Comment: I can't find a way to append `TextSendMessage(text = ...)` to an existing list. Getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_json_dict' every time.